# How can I fix this Type Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

when I try to execute this function, I get a type error

```
for i, value in enumerate(line_score):
     print(i, value)
     if (value["GAME_SEQUENCE"] != game_sequence):
           game_sequence += 1
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

value of line_sccore is

```
         GAME_DATE_EST  GAME_SEQUENCE     GAME_ID     TEAM_ID  
0  2018-02-15T00:00:00              1  0021700865  1610612743   
1  2018-02-15T00:00:00              1  0021700865  1610612749   
2  2018-02-15T00:00:00              2  0021700866  1610612747   
3  2018-02-15T00:00:00              2  0021700866  1610612750
```

`print(i, value)` gives 0 GAME_DATE_EST

Comment: thanks @DyZ, How can I fix this??

Comment: What do you expect `value["GAME_SEQUENCE"] `  to mean?  If `value` is a string, then that is invalid, as the error message says, what are you trying to do?

Comment: If `value` is a string "GAME_DATE_EST", why do you expect `value["GAME_SEQUENCE"]` to work?

Comment: @DyZ How can I check game_sequence then?

Comment: What is the type of `line_score`? Is it perhaps a pandas dataframe? What is the type and the value of `game_sequence`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to count the number of games in game_sequence with game_sequence being a simple variable?

I used this dataset you provided.

```
line_score = pd.DataFrame({"GAME_DATA_EST":["2018-02-15T00:00:00","2018-02-15T00:00:00","2018-02-15T00:00:00","2018-02-15T00:00:00"],
                       "GAME_SEQUENCE":[1,1,2,2],
                       "GAME_ID":["0021700865","0021700865","0021700866","0021700866"],
                       "TEAM_ID":[1610612743,1610612749 ,1610612747,1610612750]})
```

This code adds +1 to game_sequence if the value of GAME_SEQUENCE (in your dataset) is different.

```
game_sequence = 0
for i, value in enumerate(line_score["GAME_SEQUENCE"]):
    #print(i, value)
    if (value != game_sequence):
        game_sequence += 1

# Alternative solution
game_sequence = 0
for i, value in enumerate(line_score):
    #print(i, value)
    if (line_score["GAME_SEQUENCE"][i] != game_sequence):
        game_sequence += 1
```

Let me know if you mean something different.

Answer (score -4):

value['game-sequence'] is referencing the dictionary known as 'value', obviously 'value' is not a dictionary as u think it is, but it is a string, and you can in fact reference characters inside strings like lists, which require integers